# horizontal red line in barcode scanner app using axing library

Tags: java, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to make an app for barcode scanner. the thing is that I'm confusing right now in camera the red line is vertical and I want to make it horizontal how can I change it. I tried to do in ViewfinderView.java file but that file is locked and it doesn't change.

[that's how it looks like in the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uekgn.png)

Comment: Rotate the view finder 90 degrees counter-clockwise. The way the text will be more readable as well.

Comment: I can't change anything in the file because the file locked how can I change it

Answer (score 0):

You can just customize how you it'll look like.

check this [link](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) for more documentation

Comment: it doesn't work like that does anyone have another idea ? thank you though Joel